# Dynamic Logo Re-sizing using HTML or CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dynamic

Hi trying to figure out how to dynamically resize a logo, when i use percentages it uses a percentage of the whole page not the div that contains it.

```
<img src="Images/logo.png" name="logo" id="logo">
<div id="top_border"></div>
<img id="background" src="Images/BG_1.jpg">
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Double check that your container has a width set because your image size will be relative to that

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS File add :

```
img {
width: 20%;
max-width: 300px;
height: auto;
}
```

And if you want to enforce a fixed max width of the image, just place it inside a container, for example:

```
<div style="max-width:300px;">
    <img src="image/example.jpg" />
</div>
```